# Wrong Subsubsection numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have changed all headings to be indented by the same amount.

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\bfseries}
{\makebox[1cm][l]{\thesection}}{0cm}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\bfseries}
{\makebox[1cm][l]{\thesubsection}}{0cm}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\bfseries}
{\makebox[1cm][l]{\thesubsection}}{0cm}{}
```

Without having changed the numbering of them, the subsections are missing their last number (e.g. 3.1 instead of 3.1.1). However, in the toc they appear correct. How can I fix this?

Comment: You've got `\thesubsection` rather than `\thesubsubsection`.

Comment: Well, there's `\thesubsection` instead of `\thesubsubsection` in the third `\titleformat` command.